# OCI IAAS Object Update API

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Is there any API available in OCI to update an existing object in the bucket. Or can you please suggest any other alternative to this? I'm looking for a way to update the existing file.

Comment: Did you try `oci os object put` ? this allows to create a new object or overwrite an existing one. If this is what you are looking for, the same operation exists in the rest API or using the SDK. Let me know, I can provide a full example but 1st I need to be sure to understand your question. An exemple `oci os object put -ns mynamespace -bn mybucket --name
  myfile.txt --file /Users/me/myfile.txt --metadata
  '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}''

Comment: here a link to the API documentation for the same operation https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/objectstorage/20160918/Object/PutObject

Comment: Yes i'm using this only for creating new objects. Objects with same name are getting replaced with new content. I was looking for a way to update the same object (old + new content in same file)

Comment: ObjectStorageClient.put_object this is the method I'm calling from a python script

Comment: the only way that I found is to enable versioning at bucket level but I am not sure if this solve your issue. I suggest also read the documentation for all details  https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Object/Tasks/usingversioning.htm.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, Can you try using object versioning.

To enable object versioning after bucket creation
`oci os bucket update --namespace <object_storage_namespace> --name <bucket_name> --compartment-id <target_compartment_id> --versioning Enabled`

To list object versions
`oci os object list-object-versions --namespace <object_storage_namespace> --bucket-name <bucket_name>`

To get the contents of an object version
`oci os object get --name <object_name> --file path/to/file/name --version-id <version_identifier> --namespace <object_storage_namespace> --bucket-name <bucket_name>`

To delete an object version
`oci os object delete --name <object_name> --version-id <version_identifier> --namespace <object_storage_namespace> --bucket-name <bucket_name>`

to load continue to use `oci os object put`

More in the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Object/Tasks/usingversioning.htm. You can find also the way to do using the API or the SDK

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to append additional content to an uploaded object, you would need to download the existing object using the [GetObject](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/objectstorage/20160918/Object/GetObject) API, append to the downloaded content locally, and then upload that original+appended content back to object storage using the [PutObject](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/objectstorage/20160918/Object/PutObject) API.